# Fragment overlapped when replaced second time without addtobackstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

Scenario:

1. Activity add Fragment A to Framelayout.
2. Fragment A replace to Fragment B.

Until step 2, everything work perfectly.

3. Fragment B replace to Fragment B (also tried replace to Fragment A).

When using addToBackStack() in Step 3, everything work perfectly. Output will be A>B>B(recreated)>B(onBackPressed()/popBackStack())>A.

But when I not using addToBackStack() in Step 3, output will be A>B>B(recreated)>A (overlapped with B).

Any reason why overlap happened?

Activity add Fragment A:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    ChartFragment fragment = new ChartFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Fragment A replace to Fragment B:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        ChildChartFragment fragment = new ChildChartFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        fragment.setArguments(b);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Recreate Fragment B:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new ChildChartFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set background color in your fragments.

Comment: It worked. Just wonder why overlap happen without using background color to hide the Fragment B. It that mean the Fragment B did not remove when replace to Fragment A?

Comment: ohk. I am glad that it worked. Yes exactly it is in the background, It wasn't removed so we need to set a background for every fragment or you might face this issue.